# In the Codex Alera, do we ever see a manifestation of metal furies?

Tags: codex-alera

I remember all the other manifestations, but I can't seem to recall any of the metal.

Comment: Where they at the battle of Alera Imperia? Offhand that's where I'd look.

Am I right in assuming that you're not counting Gaius Sextus's and Araris Valerian's signature metalcrafting trick as "manifesting"? Certainly it's different from other manifestions of furycraft, but it's also not quite like the internal uses, either.

Comment: @rsegal AFAIK that is the only equivalent of "manifestation" for a metal fury we see; manifesting a fury is supposed to require a very high level of skill and only those two are shown to have it.

Comment: This is a good point, but I don't think that is exactly the case. It might be close and it definitely shows a huge level of skill in metal crafting, but I don't think it is a manifestation. In particular, it doesn't have a separate form from the crafter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After asking this question, I did some searching and found the Codex Alera section of the Jim Butcher forum. He actually [mentioned](http://www.jimbutcheronline.com/bb/index.php/topic,840.msg134574.html#msg134574) this at one point.

> Other disciplines, like metalcrafting, don't really /have/ much in the way of manifestation, so Tavi isn't at nearly as much at a disadvantage in that one.  (There is manifestation in metal furies, but it's pretty extreme and we haven't seen it yet.)

So I suppose we will just have to wait to see if Butcher writes another Alera novel to find out what it would look like.

EDIT: As of Butcher's AMA on Sept 22, 2015 we have a partial [answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/books/comments/3lye65/i_am_jim_butcher_author_of_the_dresden_files_and/cvaehmz):

> Q: Are manifest metal furies common?
>
> A: Not at all! It almost universally results in the death of the furycrafter who does it, so it tends to be frowned upon, or done as a kind of statement of "I'm going to die now--but I'm not going to make it easy for them."

Comment: Correct.  Though, Butcher has said that if he does revisit Alera, it would be a couple hundred years later during a steam-tech period.  It would be interesting to see metal manifestation in that context.

Comment: That was my thought. I figured it might be something like Brandon Sanderson's Mistborn series, followed by _The Alloy of Law_. I would love to read about that.

Comment: Yea, although I think Butcher would get into how Furycrafting it used to create/help the tech, whereas Sanderson didn't touch on that at all (not that I'm complaining).

Comment: I think what he's implying there is the metal-skin maneuver seen in the last two books.

Comment: @Radhil See my comment on the question. I mentioned why I don't believe that is considered a manifestation.